# Run java program in every 15 minutes

Tags: java, multithreading

Following is a sample code from my program which queries the database and results are copied to different files in a directory. What I want to achieve is following code should run in 15 minutes interval so that Files are updated with the new data.

```
public class CountryLogtoCSV {

static Connection con = null;
static ResultSet rs = null;

public static void main(String... argv)
{
FileWriter  filewriter=null;

File countryHits=new File("countryhits.csv");
filewriter=new FileWriter(countryHits);
query = "SELECT countryID, count(*) as total FROM mobileCountryLog"
        + " WHERE aHitType='ALL' AND aDate>'2012-11-06' GROUP BY countryID";

rs = Database.getResult(connection,query)
while (rs.next()) {

    //Writing result to File, FileWriter is used 
    filewriter.append(rs.getString("countryID"));
    filewriter.append(rs.getString("total"));
    filewriter.flush();
}   

File countryUnique=new File("countryunique.csv");
filewriter=new FileWriter(countryUnique);
query = "SELECT countryID, count(*) as total FROM mobileCountryLog"
        + " WHERE (aHitType='UNIQUE'AND aDate>'2012-11-06' GROUP BY countryID;

rs = Database.getResult(connection,query)
while (rs.next()) {

    //Writing Result to File, FileWriter is used
    filewriter.append(rs.getString("countryID"));
    filewriter.append(rs.getString("total"));
    filewriter.flush();
}   
rs.close(); 

}

}
```

How to run this java class in every 15 minutes??

Thanks,

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Comment: It depends on how you want to achieve this goal. You can use OS schedulers, Java based schedulers or just a main thread managing this.

Comment: @home I would prefer java based schedulers if possible. How can I implement scheduler in this class, any sample or example?

Comment: @SantoshGokak already gone through this tutorial, but need to know how to implement in my class?? Where to implement and how my class can run in 15 mins terminal period?

Comment: @MadanMadan i have pasted a answer which should work for your requirements.

Comment: @Santos..Thanks a Lot! When you wrote //Your Application logic means should I write there my sql queries, filewriter.append in this??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running on Unix type OS, then you can do this with [cron](http://www.pantz.org/software/cron/croninfo.html):

Add this to the crontab:

```
*/15 * * * * /yourpath-to-jdk/bin/java -cp yourclasspath CountryLogtoCSV
```

You can also do it in Java using the Executor package, but that means you will have to have that code running at all time or else it won't execute. With cron, your code only needs to run every 15 minutes (or whatever you set the time to be). This means that if your server reboots or your code crashes at one time, it will try again at the next cycle. Much more stable and easier to manage.

Comment: Yeah, I am running this on Linux , apache tomcat. Any sample?

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial http://www.pantz.org/software/cron/croninfo.html. Cron is really simple to use, you just need to make sure that the entry in the crontab (shown above) has all the paths fully specified.

Comment: @Going through it, also when I see inside init.d folder in my server there are so many files.. !! should I create another similar file and copy your command there?

Comment: You don't need to edit init.d. All you should have to do is edit the crontab by adding the above line (with the paths adjusted according to your local drive paths). May be look at a simpler tutorial: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) for this

Here is an example:-

```
   import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.*;
  class BeeperControl {
private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
   Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

public void beepForAnHour() {
    final Runnable beeper = new Runnable() {
            public void run() { System.out.println("beep"); }
        };
    final ScheduledFuture<?> beeperHandle =
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, 10, 10, SECONDS);
    scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { beeperHandle.cancel(true); }
        }, 60 * 60, SECONDS);
}
}
```

Comment: Yeah I have already gone through it, But I need to know how to use ScheduledExecutorService in my class? Any idea to implement it in my class?

Comment: Just updated it with an example...Hope that resolves your query!!

Comment: @Rahul.. This example is from the same Java tutorial. Gone through it, but I am not able to implement this in my class... that is the main problem. As I have queries, FileWriter used .. where to use ScheduledFuture in my class? Any suggestion please..

Answer (score 1):

In you case you need to bundle up your code something like this.

```
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.*;
public class CountryLogtoCSV{
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
       Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    public void logtoCSV() {
        final Runnable logger= new Runnable() {
                //You application logic as shown in the question
            };
        final ScheduledFuture<?> loggerHandle =
            scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(logger, 15, 15, MINUTES );

    //Incase you want to kill this after some time like 24 hours
        scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
                public void run() { loggerHandle.cancel(true); }
            }, 24, HOURS );
    }
 }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @Santos..Thanks a Lot! When you wrote //Your Application logic means should I write there my sql queries, filewriter.append in this??

Comment: @MadanMadan Yes that should have you application logic that takes cares of your tasks like querying DB, Making HTTP calls,etc

Comment: @Santos...It gave me the following exception in the line  Runnable logger=new Runnable()

anonymous CountryLogtoCSV  is not abstract and and does not override abstract method run() in java.lang.Runnable

How should I implement run method here?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html should give you more insights into writing threading and concurrency in java

Comment: @Santosh.. Thanks a lot..  Did it successfully!!

Answer (score 0):

Better you can go with quartz scheduler to execute your code periodically. try with the below reference

http://www.mkyong.com/java/quartz-scheduler-example/

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use the schedulers and do not want to change the time limits, most basic solution is to use a simple thread, and sleep for (15*90*1000) miliseconds... Helpful and effective if you do not want to use 3rd party s/w.